# How to create git repository for a directory and a file outside the directory?

Tags: git, ubuntu, vim, github

I want to backup my `vim` configurations on `Ubuntu` in `GitHub`. It consists of a `.vim` directory and a separate file `.vimrc` outside the `.vim` directory. How should I put them into a single git repository?

I can create a git repository in the `.vim` directory via `git init`. What about the separate `.vimrc` file?

Comment: http://dotfiles.github.io  It explains  how to  manage your dotfiles, based on a symlink method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new directory (call it dot-files) and put `.vim`, `.vimrc` etc in there.
Now create symlinks from `dot-files` to the directory where they are generally stored (usually your home directory, ~)

```
ln -sv ~/dotfiles/vimrc ~/.vimrc
ln -sv ~/dotfiles/vim ~/.vim
```

This way, you have a dedicated folder for version control and synching with github. This will keep things much simple.

I'd recommend you to add other things like shell configurations, git config, (tmux configuration, if you have it) in your dotfiles. Its an elegant way to store and share your configurations.

For more details, please refer [dotfiles.github.io](http://dotfiles.github.io/)

Answer (score 3):

1. Move your `.vimrc` file into your `.vim` directory:

   ```
   $ mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vim/vimrc
   ```
2. Put your `.vim` directory under version control:

   ```
   $ cd ~/.vim
   $ git init
   $ git add .
   $ git commit
   ```
3. *If your Vim version is lower than 7.4*, create a `~/.vimrc` file with the content below *and only the content below*:

   ```
   runtime vimrc
   ```